# how do i import bulk terrain/landscape data into a running minecraft server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have written software that generates terrain and buildings (example : [Zoo Dome](https://github.com/mutantbob/minecraft-block-hack/blob/master/constructions/src/main/java/com/purplefrog/minecraftExplorer/landscape/ZooDome.java) ).  Unfortunately it requires that I stop minecraft, run my software to alter the save file, and restart minecraft.

I would like a way to load terrain into a running minecraft server from an external source (file or URL).  Bonus points if it works when the server is running on a remote machine.

[image: floating islands]

Comment: This is not possible with the vanilla server software, but using the Bukkit API + Spigot for 1.8 you can probably make a plugin for yourself that can load a schematic from a URL (an example: http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/gitschematic/). Worldedit is a plugin that also allows for editing pretty much anything in the world, also alone capable of importing local schematics, see more info [here](http://wiki.sk89q.com/wiki/WorldEdit/Clipboard#Loading_and_saving).

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that since you cannot edit a file being used by another program, what might work is to get far away from the chunks you want to edit so that the server unloads them, and then you add your terrain, you could also modify when the server unloads a chunk.
Aside from that I think there isn't anything else you could do

Comment: isn't there a way to forcibly unload chunks?

Comment: I think that the only way is to go far away from the chunk you which to unload.